# Base a parameter value of a constructor type off a property object

Tags: typescript

I have a method that takes two parameters: `field` and `value`. I am able to enforce the first parameter using `keyof T['fields']` where it matches the fields specified in `class Test`. However, I would like to also enforce the second parameter as well which is defined by the object `fields` seen in `class Test`.

Here are the classes and the type `Fields`:

```js
export type Fields = { [key: string]: StringConstructor | NumberConstructor };

export abstract class Model {
  abstract fields: Fields;
}

export class Test extends Model {
  override fields = { name: String, age: Number };
}
```

Here is where I would like to have the `value` parameter based off of the files in `class Test`. For example when `name` is passed as the first parameter the second should be a `string`, and when `age` is passed as the first parameter the second should be a number.

```js
// This is a method within the `Model` class.
static where<T extends Model>(
  this: Newable<T>, 
  field: keyof T['fields'],
  value: typeof T['fields'][field] // This doesn't work
): T;
```

The below block seems to work (but I don't think it is based on the input of `field`, I think it just might be a union of any defined type), however, when I try `Test.where(....)` I get the following error:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StringConstructor'.

```js
static where<T extends Model>(
  this: Newable<T>, 
  field: keyof T['fields'],
  value: T['fields'][keyof T['fields']]
): T;
```

This looks like it has potential, but I am still not getting it to work:

```
static where<T extends Model>(
  this: Newable<T>, 
  field: keyof T['fields'], 
  value: T['fields'][typeof field]
): T;
```

Here are some examples:

```js
Test.where('name', 'Ryan') // Valid
Test.where('name', 123456) // Invalid

Test.where('age', 'Ryan') // Invalid
Test.where('age', 123456) // Valid
```

Comment: Can you try changing this in class Test?
override fields = { name: String(), age: Number() };

Comment: It kind of works, but it still it then accepts a parameter of `string | number` instead of just a `string` or just a `number`.

Comment: Check this  https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-bognhd

Comment: @roanjain that looks like it works (with a little modification). `export type Fields<T extends Model> = { [K in keyof T['fields']]: T['fields'][K] };` and `where<K extends keyof Fields<this>>(field: K, value: Fields<this>[K]): this;`